Struggling to setup a Validator
I've recently began setting up a Solana Validator via an Amazon EC2 instance. I understand in the long-term, it is an inefficient strategy and once I launch it properly, I am switching to a data center.
I've set up a r6a.8xlarge instance with 3 EBS gp3 volumes, just as this article suggests (https://solana.com/developers/guides/rpc/configure-solana-rpc-on-aws).
I created a sol user, made the necessary file systems and directories, mounted them, tuned my system, copied my local validator-keypair.json and vote-account-keypair.json files to the remote server, created a validator.sh script, and pasted the default info from the validator setup-up docs (https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/setup-a-validator) into the startup script.
However, when I run the command
/home/sol/bin/validator.sh

It runs for approximately 40 seconds and then stops. Furthermore, when I tail the logs, I get multiple errors that state:
ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8899, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8900, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8000, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation

And of course the:
solana gossip | grep <myPubkey>

and
solana validators | grep <myPubkey>

commands return nothing as well.
I've also reconfigured my internet’s port forwarding settings because I've been told this is the cause of those errors but it hasn't solved it.
I would sincerely appreciate any help you can offer. I have been struggling for the past couple weeks to set this up. You can reach me via email at hades8aker@gmail.com. Thank you so much!
